# how to get an xml element value in powershell

Tags: powershell

im new to powershell,
i want to make a script that monitors a folder for xml files being created.
i want the script to perform  a simple task if a certain element value is found in the xml.
here is an example of an xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<recognitionevent>
<eventnumber>7457</eventnumber>
<checkpoint>2</checkpoint>
<speed>0</speed>
<length>0</length>
<stringdata>Checkpoint 2</stringdata>
<pin/>
<rfid/>
<carddata/>
<unitdetected>0</unitdetected>
<trailerdetected>0</trailerdetected>
<date>
<year>2018</year>
<month>03</month>
<day>05</day>
<hour>18</hour>
<minute>40</minute>
<second>51</second>
</date>
<frontlicenseplates>
<licenseplate>
<unformatted>9224026</unformatted>
<formatted>9224026</formatted>
<nationality>ISR</nationality>
<confidence>0.993321</confidence>
<timestamp>20180305184052135</timestamp>
<imagefile>C:\Program Files\DynamTech\Images\Visy\2018\03\05\18\20180305184051_2_7457_Front23.jpg</imagefile>
</licenseplate>
</frontlicenseplates>
</recognitionevent>
```

and this is the script

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\source"
$watcher.Filter = "*.xml*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  


$action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            $xml = [xml](get-content $Path)
            $checkpoint = $xml.recognitionevent | Select checkpoint
            $licenseplate = $xml.recognitionevent.frontlicenseplates.licenseplate | Select formatted
            $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
            $logline = "$licenseplate, $checkpoint"
            Add-content "C:\Users\bill\Documents\Script\log.txt" -Value $logline
          }    

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 1}
```

it works, but it returns the value of **$checkpoint** and **$licenseplate**
 as **@{checkpoint=2}** and **@{licenseplate=9224026}**

i don't know why it happens. i want to use it the terms in an *if* statement like:

```
                If ($checkpoint -eq 2)
                {
                $command = @'
cmd.exe /C powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file C:\Users\bill\Documents\Script\arduino.ps1 COM5 9600 0
'@

                Invoke-Expression -Command:$command
                }
```

but i can't

Comment: Try $checkpoint = $xml.recognitionevent.checkpoint

Comment: Also, why are you shelling out to cmd from powershell to run powershell to run a powershell script?

Comment: that worked thank you. the cmd is a mistake i was just trying to make example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Something like this:

```
$checkpoint = $xml.recognitionevent.checkpoint
$licenseplate = $xml.recognitionevent.frontlicenseplates.licenseplate.formatted
```